# Ajax Request on jQuery Mobile using with Codeginiter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, jquery-mobile

Currently Im trying to do ajax request using jQuery Mobile. I`m trying to use example on http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=2574. Yes, it works perfectly. But problems was coming when i tried to use the code inside codeigniter.

Here is my controller :

```
<?php
class Ajax extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct() {

    }

    function index() {
        ?>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
            <title>Submit a form via AJAX</title>
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.min.css" />
              <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
              <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <script>
                function onSuccess(data, status)
                {
                    data = $.trim(data);
                    $("#notification").text(data);
                }

                function onError(data, status)
                {
                    // handle an error
                }        

                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#submit").click(function(){

                        var formData = $("#callAjaxForm").serialize();

                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "callajax",
                            cache: false,
                            data: formData,
                            success: onSuccess,
                            error: onError
                        });

                        return false;
                    });
                });
            </script>

            <!-- call ajax page -->
            <div data-role="page" id="callAjaxPage">
                <div data-role="header">
                    <h1>Call Ajax</h1>
                </div>

                <div data-role="content">
                    <form id="callAjaxForm">
                        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                            <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" value=""  />

                            <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" value=""  />
                            <h3 id="notification"></h3>
                            <button data-theme="b" id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

                <div data-role="footer">
                    <h1>GiantFlyingSaucer</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
        </html>
        <?php
    }

    function callajax() {
        echo "ok";
    }
}
```

I want to display 'ok' in notification. I`m trying to call function callajax instead of call from callajax.php is this possible or do I need to create callajax.php? 
I`ve tried to create callajax.php but it was failed.

Thank you,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want the url to be:

```
 url: "ajax/callajax",
```

As you are calling the callajax function within the controller ajax.

Comment: Wow, it works !! Thank you.. Is it just the same if I try to call xml or json from callajax() ? of course after calling xml view and load it inside callajax().

Comment: For this purpose you can treat ajax/callajax as your 'page'. Ie. if you go to yourdomain.com/ajax/callajax you will see the message "ok". So you can do whatever you want in that function, and it will be returned as normal. Linking to xml files, you would do normally. If they were at yourdomain.com/xml/my-xml.xml then just link with site_url(xml/my-xml.xml).

Comment: No worries. And do I need to let you know that everything in your index function should be in a view? I'm guessing you simplified to give the example, so just ignore me. :)